# Is it possible to use capture result in rewrite module second condition?

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

What I am trying to achieve is following, grab the number from the query parameter and see if it exists in referrer header.

What I've got so far (clearly doesn't work):

```
<rule name="Epic rule in progress, maybe." stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my/path/goes/here" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^foo=.*-([0-9]+)$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern=".*{R:1}.*" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="666" statusReason="IDK yet." statusDescription="The end is near." />
</rule>
```

Similar bit slightly different approach (not entirely sure I can fetch query params from match URL):

```
<rule name="Epic rule in progress, maybe." stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^my\/path\/goes\/here\?foo=([0-9])" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern=".*{R:1}.*" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="666" statusReason="IDK yet." statusDescription="The end is near." />
</rule>
```

Example scenario:

- user lands on page "/mypage-123"
- JS on the page triggers a request to "my/path/goes/here?foo=123" (referrer is "/mypage-123")
- If "123" does not exist in referer, throw status code 666.

The question is:

- Is it actually possible to achieve what I am trying above?
- Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you tell me why you want to add the the condition to the pattern? I am not very clear about your Example scenario, You can tell me what your specific requirement are.

Comment: @samwu doing the following thing would help to "protect" API endpoint from not very sophisticated bots.

Comment: It's like a sanity check if referer is missing that number from query parameters, means that someone blindly took endpoint, but random referrer header and started battering it with requests.

Comment: *put random referrer header

Comment: When you use JS to make a request, url rewrite has already been executed. js captures the URL displayed in the browser, after rewriting, js captures the previous URL. when redirecting, the browser is the redirected url, and what js gets is that. The rewriting process is over, and you want to use js to finish catching and then define the status code. This is impossible.